# Android, pagination on server side

Tags: android, sql, pagination

I would like to implement pagination in my app.

I have the concept clear from the Android client side, using `RecyclerView` and bla bla bla.

My question is on the server side: I will have a DB storing info sent by app users, should each new entry of my DB include a field `page` so that, when clients make calls to the server a field `page` is sent and used on the SQL query to the database?

If not, how is the `pagination` implemented on server's DB side??.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5,10
```

will get you row 6 to 15 in a SQL DB
but you probably shouldn't call your db directly but rather wrap an api 
 around with spring for example

Comment: well...basically I would have a PHP file on the server taking care of the DB calls and returning a JSON response, not sure if that is what you mean with wrapping an api around